# CloudFront 404 Errors in Some Geographic Locations

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am using S3 and CloudFront to host some static css and js files for my website. It seems to work fine until I browse the site using an IP address from a different geographic location via NordVPN. Some locations won't load the files, return a 404, and when trying to load the files directly I get the following error:

```
<Error>
<Code>NoSuchBucket</Code>
<Message>The specified bucket does not exist</Message>
<BucketName>d13e8hu04z6mof.cloudfront.net</BucketName>
<RequestId>EA71B681E68A5644</RequestId>
<HostId>WDXHLAt6QdlOaoe21dHv/bXxZfDaY19mietZxd5alr/50ghB1u+CoJ8UyDv1PB299KsKEo8oyrU=</HostId>
</Error>
```

Why would I get this error in some locations and not others?

Comment: What does the URL look like you're trying to access? The error message looks like you're trying to access an S3 bucket called `d13e8hu04z6mof.cloudfront.net`. I suspect this is your CloudFront distribution and not the name of the origin bucket.

Comment: It is not the URL of the source bucket, but isn't it what you need to access if you want to serve that bucket from the CDN?

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly an answer for your original question, but I suggest you use CloudFront and S3 with Origin Access Identity (OAI). In this way it will protect your bucket and will avoid some of commom issues like this one you are facing.
You have other options as well, like S3 as static website or S3 as custom origin on CloudFont, but using it directly with OAI is a good practice.

See some documentations below about how to do it.

The first option from link below is what I am suggesting you:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-serve-static-website/

More detailed documentation:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html